# PermissionDeniedException: User '[UserImpl:'admin']' was unable to execution operation 'Start' on task id 1 due to a no 'current status' match

Tags: jboss, jbpm, bpmn

I'm working on jBPM6 and jboss6.2 and trying to create an application with different levels like Employee, Lead and Director. Lead and Director are Groups. After creating process, I just   as an Employee sent a some request and process moved to Lead, He has approved the request and process moved to Director, Once he is trying to approve it is throwing the following error.

```
[org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-5) Could not commit session: org.jbpm.services.task.exception.PermissionDeniedException: User '[UserImpl:'admin']' was unable to execution operation 'Start' on task id 1 due to a no 'current status' match
at org.jbpm.services.task.internals.lifecycle.MVELLifeCycleManager.evalCommand(MVELLifeCycleManager.java:128) [jbpm-human-task-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
at org.jbpm.services.task.internals.lifecycle.MVELLifeCycleManager.taskOperation(MVELLifeCycleManager.java:318) [jbpm-human-task-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
at org.jbpm.services.task.identity.UserGroupLifeCycleManagerDecorator.taskOperation(UserGroupLifeCycleManagerDecorator.java:46) [jbpm-human-task-core-6.0.1.Final.jar:6.0.1.Final]
```

while executing the following piece of code:

```
    TaskService taskService = runtimeEngine.getTaskService();
    taskService.start(taskId, username);
    taskService.complete(taskId, username, parameterMap);
```

I'm new to BPM process flow, but tried my best to fix the problem. But didn't find solution for it. Please advise me how to solve it ? where it is going wrong like configuration or anything else ?
Thanks,
Mr.Chowdary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After putting lot of efforts, debugging the code, i came to know that in `operations-dsl.mvel` file in `jbpm-human-task-core-6.0.1.Final.jar` having operations like `Start,Complete,Fail,Exit` and etc.
In that the current status is not defined. It is happeneing due to some errors while completing the task. Eg:

```
taskService.start(taskId, username);
```

Before this step, the status is "Ready"
After executing this step, the status will be "InProgress"

```
taskService.complete(taskId, username, parameterMap);
```

While executing `complete()`, if any exception cause, then the status will be `"InProgress"` only
So if user tries to complete the task, it will start with `start()` method, in that method status `"InProgress"` is not defined. So it throws the following exception.

```
[org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-5) Could not commit session: org.jbpm.services.task.exception.PermissionDeniedException: User '[UserImpl:'admin']' was unable to execution operation 'Start' on task id 1 due to a no 'current status' match
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the "admin" user, use any other user which belongs to the Director group.